# shell mock --define from array: ERROR: Bad option for '--define' ("dist). Use --define 'macro expr'

Tags: arrays, shell, mocking

I am currently writing a script which should make it more easy for me to build some RPMs using mock.
The plan is to make it possible to add values for the mock (and therefor rpmbuild) --define parameter.
The error I get if I add such a define value is

> ERROR: Bad option for '--define' ("dist).  Use --define 'macro expr'

When I execute the script with as simple as ./test.sh --define "dist .el7" the "debug" output is as follows:

> /usr/bin/mock --init -r epel-7-x86_64 --define "dist .el7"

If I copy this and execute it in the shell directly it is actually working. Does anybody have an idea why this is the case?

My script can be cut down to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

C_MOCK="/usr/bin/mock"

MOCK_DEFINES=()

_add_mock_define() {
  #_check_parameters_count_strict 1 ${#}
  local MOCK_DEFINE="${1}"

  MOCK_DEFINES+=("${MOCK_DEFINE}")
}

_print_mock_defines_parameter() {
  if [ ${#MOCK_DEFINES[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    return 0
  fi

  printf -- "--define \"%s\" " "${MOCK_DEFINES[@]}"
}

_mock_init() {
  local MOCK_DEFINES_STRING="$(_print_mock_defines_parameter)"
  local MOCK_PARAMS="--init"
  MOCK_PARAMS="${MOCK_PARAMS} -r epel-7-x86_64"
  [ ! "${#MOCK_DEFINES_STRING}" -eq 0 ] && MOCK_PARAMS="${MOCK_PARAMS} ${MOCK_DEFINES_STRING}"

  echo "${C_MOCK} ${MOCK_PARAMS}"
  ${C_MOCK} ${MOCK_PARAMS}

  local RC=${?}

  if [ ${RC} -ne 0 ]; then
      _exit_error "Error while mock initializing ..." ${RC}
  fi
}

while (( ${#} )); do
  case "${1}" in
    -s|--define)
      shift 1
      _add_mock_define "${1}"
      ;;
  esac

  shift 1
done

_mock_init

exit 0
```

Comment: A friend just told me to execute the script with bash -x _script_ and the interesting point is the following: `+ /usr/bin/mock --init -r epel-7-x86_64 --define '"dist' '.el7"'
ERROR: Bad option for '--define' ("dist).  Use --define 'macro expr'` - there seems to be an issue with the whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking this question a coworker I was pointed to this question on unix stackexchange: [Unix Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416571/why-is-using-eval-necessary-to-pass-quoted-arguments/416578#416578)
The way this problem was solved can be broken down to following lines:

```
DEFINES=()
DEFINES+=(--define "dist .el7")
DEFINES+=(--define "foo bar")
/usr/bin/mock --init -r epel-7-x86_64 "${DEFINES[@]}"
```

Just in case somebody else stumbles upon this kind of issue.